# Observe one LiveData into other LiveData Observr

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

I have two `LiveData`:

1. `MutableLiveData<Int>` -User could choose number by taping at "+" and "-" buttton.
2. LiveData> - it's my data from RoomData base by call method `getLessonsForThatDay(number:Int)`.

I have to update my method getLessonForThatDay(value) with that MutableLiveData value.

I've tried to use MediatorLiveData<> but i don't get it.

```
viewModel.dayOfWeek.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { dayOfWeekValue ->
        d("$dayOfWeekValue")
        viewModel.getLessonsForThatDay(dayOfWeekValue).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { lessons ->
            adapter.updateData(lessons)
            subjectsListTimetableRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            subjectsListTimetableRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        })
    })
```

- List item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your `viewmodel` define a `liveData` like this.

```
private val dayOfWeekChangRequest = MutableLiveData<Int>()
```

and a method like this, when + , - clicked, call this method.

```
fun dayOfWeekChanged(dayOfWeek: Int) {

    dayOfWeekChangRequest.value = dayOfWeek
}
```

now add a live data for `lessonsOfThatDay`

```
val lessonsForThatDay: LiveData<List<Lesson>> = Transformations
        .switchMap(dayOfWeekChangRequest) { day ->
            yourDataBaseRepository.getLessonsOfThatDay(day)
        }
```

with this transformation, every time you change your `dayOfWeek`, the `lessonsForThatDay` value will be changed.

at last in your activity observe it

```
viewModel.lessonsForThatDay.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { 
        lessons ->
        adapter.updateData(lessons)
        subjectsListTimetableRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        subjectsListTimetableRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    })
```

Comment: That's works for me. Thanks bro, I wasted about 4 days for that ; ) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do `viewModel = Dao.getLessonsForThatDay(number)`. This way, the viewmodel will listen to changes in Dao